# Clearcase to Git migration issues

Tags: git, migration, clearcase

I am migrating from ClearCase to Git and have two problems:

1. Somebody from my team pushed one of his side branches into "origin/master" branch and screwed up the branch. I have a local repo "master" and I would like to push it completely and make it exact to my branch. How do I do this?
2. I have two branches on my computer -
   I would like to know the diff between them and make a script that people can run from different computers and reapply all the changes (deletion, insertions and modifications).
3. (COMMENT about 2) very important: the two branches were created like so:
   The two branches - one is more advanced than the other -- that is, it contains changes the other doesn't have, and the other as no versions the first one doesn't have.

That is, it is not a fork. Hope that simplifies things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)

```
git push -f origin master
```

The `-f` overwrites the remote branch with yours.

(2)

This will get the commit ids between `branch1` and `branch2`.

```
git log --pretty=format:%h branch1..branch2
```

You can then go to each by doing `git checkout abc123`.

BTW, what are you looking to do with #2? There are many really great built-in git features, such as `git bisect`, that may solve your problem.

**EDIT**:

(A) If you want to keep commit history, you should create a patch with

```
 git format-patch branch1..branch2 --stdout > my_patch.patch
```

This will have a patch of all changes between `branch1` and `branch2`. Then apply it with

```
 git am < my_patch.patch
```

(B) If you just want the changes, without the commits,

```
 git diff branch1..branch2 > my_patch..patch
```

and then

```
 git apply < my_patch
```

Comment: Hi, I want to prepare a patch - so that people from other branches get the changes I made, even though they have a different. Actually, I want a script to put in a shared location that will re-play / re-apply the changes I made to their repository.